# How do I Parse this XML

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I need to parse the XML below using Visual Basic .NET. In the past I found a workaround through XSLT, adapting the XML to my needs, but I seriously want to know how this needs to be done without workarounds. I'll paste the XML first, and then I'll let you know where and why I get stuck:

```
<browse result="1" first="1" last="16" total="16">
    <th>
        <td label="dimension" hideforuser="false" type="String">fin.trs.line.dim2</td>
        <td label="Outstanding" hideforuser="false" type="Value">fin.trs.line.openbasevaluesigned</td>
        <td label="Factuurbedrag" hideforuser="false" type="Value">fin.trs.line.basevaluesigned</td>
        <td label="Invoice Number" hideforuser="false" type="String">fin.trs.line.invnumber</td>
        <td label="" hideforuser="false" type="String">fin.trs.head.code</td>
        <td label="Pay date" hideforuser="false" type="Date">fin.trs.line.matchdate</td>
        <td label="Vervaldatum" hideforuser="false" type="Date">fin.trs.line.datedue</td>
        <td label="Datum" hideforuser="false" type="Date">fin.trs.head.date</td>
        <td label="boektype" hideforuser="false" type="String">fin.trs.head.status</td>
        <td label="paystatus" hideforuser="false" type="String">fin.trs.line.availableforpayruns</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.dim2" hideforuser="false" type="String">01603</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.openbasevaluesigned" hideforuser="false" type="Value">-792.00</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.basevaluesigned" hideforuser="false" type="Value">-800.00</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.invnumber" hideforuser="false" type="String">789</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.head.code" hideforuser="false" type="String">INK</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.matchdate" hideforuser="false" type="Date" name="14/03/2012">20120314</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.datedue" hideforuser="false" type="Date" name="13/04/2012">20120413</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.head.date" hideforuser="false" type="Date" name="14/03/2012">20120314</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.head.status" hideforuser="false" type="String" name="Definitief">final</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.availableforpayruns" hideforuser="false" type="String" name="Ja">true</td>
        <key>
            <office>DACMI3-1</office>
            <code>INK</code>
            <number>201200019</number>
            <line>1</line>
        </key>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.dim2" hideforuser="false" type="String">11123</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.openbasevaluesigned" hideforuser="false" type="Value">300.00</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.basevaluesigned" hideforuser="false" type="Value">300.00</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.invnumber" hideforuser="false" type="String">11112</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.head.code" hideforuser="false" type="String">INK</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.matchdate" hideforuser="false" type="Date"/>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.datedue" hideforuser="false" type="Date" name="13/04/2012">20120413</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.head.date" hideforuser="false" type="Date" name="14/03/2012">20120314</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.head.status" hideforuser="false" type="String" name="Definitief">final</td>
        <td field="fin.trs.line.availableforpayruns" hideforuser="false" type="String" name="Ja">true</td>
        <key>
            <office>DACMI3-1</office>
            <code>INK</code>
            <number>201200021</number>
            <line>1</line>
        </key>
    </tr>
    </browse>
```

To keep it readable for everyone I have truncated the XML. There are about 15 more `<tr>` sections in the actual XML. The XML is a response I'm getting from a webservice.

I've tried every piece of code I could find on the web, but I got stuck on each and everyone of them. That's why I'm not going to show you what I tried already, please take my word for it that I've spent two years on it.

**What is my problem**:

**1**. As you can see the XML starts out with a `<th>` section (which is not of importance to me, that is simply the webservice telling me what I asked for). So that part needs to be disregarded. But it is on the same 'level' as the `<tr>` blocks which I DO need, so how do I skip the `<th>` one and start at the `<tr>` ones? As in a `for each tr` thing.

**2**. I need every value and name within the `<tr>` blocks, but the *names* are not specified by tags, but by attributes. If you look at the `<tr>` blocks; instead of

`<dim2>01603</dim2>`

it is put down as

```
<td field="fin.trs.line.dim2" hideforuser="false" type="String">01603</td>
```

for every `<tr>` block I need the `fin.trs.line.dim2` part (so the field name) and the actual value. So how do I do that?

**3**. Each `<tr>` block has a childnode called `<key>`, which (as it kind of tells) holds key values for each block. How do I retrieve those values, and make sure I know they belong to the `<tr>` block it is in?

I've been reading tutorials and websites forever, but I simply don't seem to be able to understand this part.

Just to make sure, this is for Visual Basic NET (2010, if you need to know).

P.S.: The XML is in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to take the `tr` elements only and then extract the *attribute* and the *value* from the `th` element using the [XDocument.Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [XAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) method. To find the *key* elements use the *Descendants* method again on the `tr` element. The solution could look like this:

```
dim xmlSource = File.ReadAllText("d:\temp\source.xml")
' read the XML (HTML) code
dim xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlSource)
' find all tr elements
dim trs = xml.Root.Descendants("tr").ToList()
' iterate over each one of them
for Each tr in trs
    ' find all td elements for each tr
    dim tds = tr.Descendants("td")
    ' iterate over each one of them
    for each td as XElement in tds
        ' find the attribute with the name field
        dim attr as XAttribute = td.Attribute("field")
        ' if found
        if not (attr.Value = nothing) then
            ' take the attribute name and the element value (td value)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", attr.Value, td.Value))
        end if
    next
    ' find element key that belongs to this tr
    dim keys = tr.Descendants("key")
    for each key as XElement in keys
        dim keyNodes = key.Elements()
        for each keyNode as XElement in keyNodes
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", keyNode.Name, keyNode.Value))
        next
    next
next
```

The output is (just a part of it):

```
...
fin.trs.head.date - 20120314
fin.trs.head.status - final
fin.trs.line.availableforpayruns - true
office - DACMI3-1
code - INK
number - 201200021
line - 1
```